# How to read a txt file already on the server with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a .txt file stored at `./example.txt` and I want a JavaScript program to read and copy over the entire .txt file and show it in `index.html` interactively (i.e. upon click of a button, say). How can I do that?

I have tried googling, but all of the solutions seem to be *asking* the user for a file and reading it, not an already existing file on the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use XML:

```
function loadText() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "./example.txt");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("text-container").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

}